# Passing variables into powershell script

Tags: php, powershell

I want to pass variables by using a form to powershell script, but this not working :( 
Index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Password Update for BHT and ADS</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
 
if(!isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    ?>
    <form name="Form1" id="Form1" action="index.php" method="post" />
        nom: <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" maxlength="20" /><br />
        prenom: <input type="text" name="prenom" id="prenom" maxlength="20" /><br />
        login: <input type="text" name="login" id="login" maxlength="100" /><br />
        mdp: <input type="text" name="mdp" id="mdp" maxlength="100" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
        
    </form>
    
    <?php    
}
elseif((isset($_POST["submit"])) && (!empty($_POST["nom"])))
{
   $nom = $_POST["nom"];
   $prenom = $_POST["prenom"];
$login= $_POST["login"];
$mdp= $_POST["mdp"];         

    $psScriptPath2 = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Test\\test2.ps1";
    
   $query2 = Shell_exec("powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -command $psScriptPath2 -nom '$nom' -prenom '$prenom' -login '$login' -mdp '$mdp'");
    echo $query2;
}
else
{
    echo "Sorry, you did not complete all required fields. Please go back and try again.";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Test2.ps1

```
param ([string]$nom,
[string]$prenom,
[string]$login,
[string]$mdp
)

write-host "$nom"
write-host "$prenom"
write-host "$login"
write-host "$mdp"

Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory

$domaine = "xxx.fr"
$OU = "OU=AA,OU,=Utilisateurs,OU=BB,OU=CC,OU=DD,DC=XXX,DC=FR"
New-ADUser `
            -SamAccountName $nom `
            -UserPrincipalName ($login + '@' + $env:userdnsdomain)  `
            -Name "$nom $prenom" `
            -GivenName $nom `
            -surname $prenom `
            -EmailAddress "$prenom.$nom@xxx.fr" `
            -Enabled $True `
            -DisplayName "$nom, $prenom" `
            -server $domaine `
            -Path $OU `
            -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $mdp -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Variable are not passing and powershell say that param is not a command... 
So 2 problems : pass variable is not working and param is shitty 
I put the exactly code 
Can I have some help ?
Ty

Comment: You powershell command contains multiple undefined variables though. The only value you actually fetch and use is `nom`. You should also use [escapeshellarg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to escape the arguments you get from the form and never ever just execute user data without escaping and validation.

Comment: Can you post the full and exact error message?

Comment: I put the original code

Comment: Param is not recognized as a cmdlet, command, fuction etc...

Comment: Don't have the error of param (must be first in the page)

Comment: But the variable don't pass :(

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73607176/edit) your question and add the full error message (copy/paste). You should also echo out the full command you're executing to check if it looks OK. You can add that to the question as well so we know what it us you're actually are executing.

Comment: Ok, it's good, I did it

Comment: @Drakov666 Except you didn't - we're still waiting to see the full error message :)

Comment: Assuming your error is ```The term 'param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.```, check that you only have one ```param()``` block in your script, and that it's the first thing in your script (or at least only has whitespace before it)...

Comment: You did what? Solve the problem? In that case, either post an answer explaining how you solved it (if you think it will be useful, but then you still need to post the error message and the full command with your values so other know _exactly_ what your answer solves), or delete the question. If that was _not_ what you meant, then you need to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the comments above, you do:

```
$query2 = Shell_exec("powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -command $psScriptPath2 -nom '$nom' -prenom '$prenom' -login '$login' -mdp '$mdp'"
```

You did use single quotes around the variables, e.g: '$nom'. This won't work, you need to use double quotes, e.g. "$nom" - otherwise PowerShell thinks its a pure string and won't resolve the variable.

reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: I might be wrong (not a PS user), but are you sure you're not mixing things up here? The variable `$nom` will be resolved by PHP before the call is even made in PS. So if `$nom` contains the string `foobar`, the command `"powershell.exe ... -nom '$nom' ..."` will be executed as `"powershell.exe ... -nom 'foobar' ..."`